# Validate a Field with Redux-form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I try learn how to works with redux-form and I have a little probleme.
For example, I have a Field component like that:

```
<Field
  name='individual.email'
  id="email"
  component={ renderInput }
  placeholder='test'
/>
```

In validate.js I have something like that:

```
 if ( !values.individual.email ) {
            errors.individual.email = 'Required'
        }
```

But I have the error :

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'email' of undefined
```

If I change the name of my Field by only 'email' it is works fine.. Any idea of what I do wrong when my Field is 'individual.email' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 if ( values.individual && !values.individual.email ) {
            errors.individual.email = 'Required'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`errors.invididual.email` is an object within the `errors` object, i.e.

```
errors = {
    individual: {
        email: 'Required'
    }
}
```

At the top of your `validate()` function, you probably have declared the `errors` object, but it doesn't know about the `individual` property on it. That is why the field being only `email` works - you have defined `errors` and are setting the `email` property on it to `required`.

I'm not sure if it works, but you would have to do something like:

```
const errors = {
    individual: {}
};
```

And then you could assign `errors.individual.email = 'Required'`

Comment: looks like a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40704827/syncerror-not-flagged-on-field-instance-with-dot-syntax-name

Comment: I have already look this question but for me it does not work because in my IF my value is impossible to read.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the problem then; the type error you mention is because `individual` is undefined on your `errors` object

Comment: Yes but even if I created the error object  with individual like your sample I can not set the error.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the name field so it’s not using a dot. Use it `individualEmail` would be the standard way of naming.  You shouldn’t use a . In names

Comment: In the documentation is possible : The name prop is required. It is a string path, in dot-and-bracket notation, corresponding to a value in the form values. It may be as simple as 'firstName' or as complicated as 'contact.billing.address[2].phones[1].areaCode'.

Comment: ‘individual.name’ is the value of the name property.  You can’t use a value in dot or bracket notation.

Comment: What is the link between the name of the field and the values errors ?

Comment: In my Fields I arranged to create a JSON document as I wanted it and I want to be able to associate a specific message on each field. When I do the submission I see that the `name` value is for example in` individual.name`. So I would like to be able to specify error message in my variable errors

Comment: [here](https://redux-form.com/7.2.3/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/) is a great doc page about using field-level validation with redux-forms.  without seeing more of your code its hard to debug further.  https://redux-form.com/7.2.3/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/

Comment: According to that documentation, you can access the name value inside of your validator function by using `props.name`.  `props.name` in the case of that field will return `individual.email` as you have named it.